# copy variable number of lines based on start and end triggers

Tags: python-2.7

I have a script that collects only the important lines of text from multiple log files and writes them to a separate text file. It works as long as I provide a string snippet to search for. Once found, it will copy the entire line of text where it found the string snippet. Now I need it to select multiple lines of text based on known starting and ending text snippets. The total number of lines between/including the starting and ending text snippets varies among the log files that I'm reading. I've searched and tried lots of things, but can't get it to work. I'm providing what I have so far.

I'm not a python newbie, but far from an expert. Any/All advice is truly appreciated.

```
import os, time, datetime, fnmatch, re
from time import strftime, time

# Open log file to record actions
dirName = "D://GISlogs//" + strftime("%Y%m%d")
global pubfilePrefix
pubfilePrefix = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
pubfileName = "D://GISlogs//" + strftime("%Y%m%d") + "//" + pubfilePrefix.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + "_SUMMARIZE_MorningActivities.txt"
if os.path.exists(pubfileName) and os.path.isfile(pubfileName) and os.access(pubfileName, os.W_OK):
    with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
        myFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  SUMMARIZING ALL GIS ACTIVITIES1" + "\r\n" + "\r\n")
else:
    try:
        os.makedirs(dirName)
        with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
            myFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  SUMMARIZING ALL GIS ACTIVITIES2" + "\r\n" + "\r\n")
    except OSError:
        if os.path.isdir(dirName):
            with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
                myFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  SUMMARIZING ALL GIS ACTIVITIES3" + "\r\n" + "\r\n")

def Search_LogFile(searchPhrase, titleBlock):
    if searchPhrase == "~-~-~":
        with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
            myFile.write("\r\n" + titleBlock + "\r\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n")

    with open("D://GISlogs//" + strftime("%Y%m%d") + "//" + searchFile, "r") as readFile:
        for readLine in readFile:
            if searchPhrase in readLine:
                if re.compile("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ").match(readLine):
                    readLine = readLine[11:]
                with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
                    myFile.write(readLine)

for searchFile in os.listdir(dirName):

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(searchFile, "*COPY_TaxRollData.txt"):
        Search_LogFile("~-~-~", "Acquiring Updated Data from PVA")
        Search_LogFile(" - DELETING PREVIOUSLY DOWNLOADED PVA DATA", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - DOWNLOADING THE LATEST SNAPSHOT OF PUBLIC INQUIRY DATABASE", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - ARCHIVING ALL DOWNLOADED FILES", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - RECONCILING NEW DOWNLOAD WITH PRIOR DATA", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - EXECUTING FME MODEL TO OVERWRITE PVA DATA IN SDE", "")

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(searchFile, "*INTEGRATE_TaxRollData.txt"):
        Search_LogFile("~-~-~", "Integrating Updated Data from PVA into the SDE Production EGDB")
        Search_LogFile("|INFORM|Reading table/feature class '", "")
        Search_LogFile("|INFORM|Opened Shape File '", "")
        Search_LogFile("|INFORM|CSV reader: Opening dataset '", "")
        Search_LogFile("|ERROR |", "")
        Search_LogFile("|INFORM|Translation was SUCCESSFUL", "")
        Search_LogFile("|INFORM|FME Session Duration:", "")
        #THE NEXT 9 LINES IS MY LATEST ATTEMPT. IT WORKS OUTSIDE OF THIS BLOCK OF CODE, BUT NOT HERE
        valid=False
        for line in searchFile:
            if re.compile(".*Features Written Summary.*").match(line):
                valid=True
            if re.compile(".*Total Features Written.*").match(line):
                valid=False
            if valid:
                with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
                    myFile.write(line)
        #Search_LogFile("Features Written Summary", "")
        Search_LogFile("  PVA TAX ROLL DATA HAS BEEN RE-INTEGRATED IN THE SDE PRODUCTION DATABASE", "") 

print('\r\n' +'The Script Completed successfully')
```

To clarify further - the text "Features Written Summary" is on the line that I want my capture to begin with, and "Total Features Written" is on the line that I want my capture to end with (I want to copy the entire line where both snippets appear as well as everything in between).  Both starting and ending snippets appear only once in the log file.

@MadPhysicist When I run the code, it finds the first log file and looks for specific phrases. When it finds them it writes the entire line of text where it found the phrase to a different text file. It then looks for the next specific phrase and does the same thing. After looking for all of the specific phrases in that log file, it will find the next log file and look for a different set of phrases specific to that particular log file.  It works great.

But what I'm trying to add is a little different tweak that I can't figure out.  In the second log file, I want to copy more than one consecutive line found within it to my other text file.  I can copy the start line and end line using the method described above, but the wrinkle is that I also want to copy all of the lines of text between the start line and end line.  The number of lines between the start and end lines can vary as well, so that can't be hard-coded.

Comment: Your indentation is a bit messed up. If you don't want to nest `with` blocks (I don't), do something like `with open(...) as myFile, open(...) as readFile:`.

Comment: Don't use double *forward* slashes. You only need double backslashes

Comment: `strftime` is missing a parameter. Please show what happens what you attempt to run your code. You should at least present something that doesn't have glaring syntax errors in it.

Comment: As a general piece of advice, describe the algorithm you plan on using in words. It will make it much easier to write the code yourself.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow and still learning the etiquette (this only my second question ever). I fixed the indentation (I think). Also included omitted code (left out originally for brevity sake). Hopefully syntax errors not as "glaring" as before.

Comment: So what happens when you run this code?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I edited my post to answer you about what happens.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now, but here's an idea: have a Boolean flag that is normally off. It gets turned on when you encounter the opening sequence, and back off after you encounter a closing sequence. Lines get copied from the input to the output whenever the flag is on.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a working solution now, but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient and/or could be designed better. I'm going to put it in place, but if anyone can think of a better way to go about what I'm trying to do here, I'm all ears...

```
import os, time, datetime, fnmatch, re
from time import strftime, time

# Open log file to record actions
dirName = "D://GISlogs//" + strftime("%Y%m%d")
global pubfilePrefix
pubfilePrefix = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
pubfileName = "D://GISlogs//" + strftime("%Y%m%d") + "//" + 
pubfilePrefix.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + "_SUMMARIZE_MorningActivities.txt"
if os.path.exists(pubfileName) and os.path.isfile(pubfileName) and os.access(pubfileName, os.W_OK):
    with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
        myFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  SUMMARIZING ALL GIS ACTIVITIES1" + "\r\n" + "\r\n")
else:
    try:
        os.makedirs(dirName)
        with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
            myFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  SUMMARIZING ALL GIS ACTIVITIES2" + "\r\n" + "\r\n")
    except OSError:
        if os.path.isdir(dirName):
            with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
                myFile.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "  SUMMARIZING ALL GIS ACTIVITIES3" + "\r\n" + "\r\n")

def Search_LogFile(searchPhrase, titleBlock):
    if searchPhrase == "~-~-~":
        with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
            myFile.write("\r\n" + titleBlock + "\r\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n")

    with open("D://GISlogs//" + strftime("%Y%m%d") + "//" + searchFile, "r") as readFile:
        for readLine in readFile:
            if searchPhrase in readLine:
                if re.compile("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ").match(readLine):
                    readLine = readLine[11:]
                with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
                    myFile.write(readLine)

            if searchPhrase in readLine and searchPhrase == "Features Written Summary":
                valid=False
                for line in readFile:
                    if re.compile(".*|                           Features Written Summary.*").match(line):
                        valid = True
                    if re.compile(".*END - ProcessID.*").match(line):
                        valid = False
                    if valid:
                        if re.compile("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ").match(line):
                            line = line[11:]
                            with open(pubfileName, "a") as myFile:
                                myFile.write(line)

for searchFile in os.listdir(dirName):

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(searchFile, "*COPY_TaxRollData.txt"):
        Search_LogFile("~-~-~", "Acquiring Updated Data from PVA")
        Search_LogFile(" - DELETING PREVIOUSLY DOWNLOADED PVA DATA", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - DOWNLOADING THE LATEST SNAPSHOT OF PUBLIC INQUIRY DATABASE", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - ARCHIVING ALL DOWNLOADED FILES", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - RECONCILING NEW DOWNLOAD WITH PRIOR DATA", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - DISCONNECTING W: DRIVE", "")
        Search_LogFile(" - EXECUTING FME MODEL TO OVERWRITE PVA DATA IN SDE", "")

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(searchFile, "*INTEGRATE_TaxRollData.txt"):
        Search_LogFile("~-~-~", "Integrating Updated Data from PVA into the SDE Production EGDB")
        Search_LogFile("Reading table/feature class '", "")
        Search_LogFile("Opened Shape File '", "")
        Search_LogFile("CSV reader: Opening dataset '", "")
        Search_LogFile("|ERROR |", "")
        #Search_LogFile("|WARN  |", "")
        Search_LogFile("Features Written Summary", "")
```